# What is (if there is) the reaction between manganese chloride and oxygen when dry?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I had a chemistry lab and I did a error. I was supposed to make some $\ce{MnCl2}$ and then used fire to dry it but then some of it turned black, and I am supposed to quantify my error. So I am assuming the reaction to be between $\ce{MnCl2}$ and $\ce{O2}$ but I don't know what they make.

Answer (score 0):

Heating $\ce{MnCl2}$ in presence of air made it to oxidize and form black manganese oxides.

$$\ce{4MnCl2 + 3O2 ->[\Delta] 2Mn2O3 + 4Cl2}$$

Comment: You don't get gaseous chlorine this way, only mixture of oxides and chlorides, IMO.